# Наследование реализации

Tags: c++, наследование

Что такое наследование реализации и почему `private` наследование называют наследованием реализации?

Comment: *"private наследование называют наследованием реализации"* кто называет?

Comment: потому что такое наследование нужно только для реализации производного класса. Может поэтому кто то может так  выразится.

Comment: Почитай лучше ООП.
Есть какой то класс(родительский) и тебе нужно воспользоваться её свойствам и методами, а может ты вообще хочешь увеличить функционал данного класса, соответственно создаешь класс который будет наследоваться от родительского. т.е. ты описываешь свой класс на основе уже имеющегося класса. А private это спецификатор доступа, как public и protected.т.е. они доступны по определенным правилам.

Comment: @Ain777 ты отвечаешь на вопрос "что такое наследование", которого я не задавал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Закрытое и защищенное наследование используются для **выражения деталей реализации.**  Таким образом производный класс(и его друзья) может использовать некоторые возможности базового класса для своей реализации(как бы "ужесточить" интерфейс базового). Вот вся причина, из за которой может иметь место выражение **"класс реализации "**(про базовый класс) или **"наследование реализации "**(хоть и не совсем понятное выражение, но все же...) , когда имеется ввиду закрытое наследование.

Answer (score 0):

Пусть у моего дедушки есть ферма и есть лавка, где он продает выращенные овощи. Посетители не могут ходить прямо на ферму, за овощами им надо идти в лавку, она public. Унаследовав хозяйство, я хочу использовать ферму, но лавку открыть свою, с продавщицами и картами. Чтобы запретить посетителям пользоваться лавкой деда, я объявляю наследование хозяйства private. Заметим, что сам я не смогу напрямую ходить на ферму, если та была private, а если protected, то смогу.